# How can I define aws resource tags in terraform conditionally?

Tags: tags, terraform

I would like to define resource tags (e.g., for a DynamoDB table) only in certain environments, but not all.

I am familiar with count trick: setting the count to 0 so that a resource will not get created. But this is a field within a resource.

```
tags {
    count = "${var.is_production == "T" ? 1 : 0}"
    MyProductionOnlyTag = "${var.prod_tag_value}"
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that rather than something like an environment tag that has a value of `production` when it's production?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, I am bound to a policy where a certain tag should be defined, say, only in *dev* but does not have to be defined in *prod*. While I can define this tag in prod as well, I prefer not to clutter resources with unnecessary tags.

Comment: And you're searching for the key of the tag rather than the value? Could you use an empty string for it in dev to imply its absence? Which version of Terraform are you using?

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky, but you could use dynamic blocks (requires `terraform => 0.12`):

```
dynamic "tags" {
  iterator = my_prod_tag_value
  for_each = "${var.my_prod_tag == null ? 0 : 1 }"
  content {
    MyProductionOnlyTag = "${my_prod_tag_value}"
  }
}
```

Also, when declaring `var.my_prod_tag`, you must explicitly allow it to be null:

```
variable "my_prod_tag" {
    type = "string"
    default = null
}
```